# how to send notification on page change in dgrid using dojo/Javascript

Tags: javascript, pagination, dojo, dgrid

I am using dgrid with pagination where I have to send notification to the user that on which page of dgrid he is currently looking at.

> libraries used for dgrid/Pagination:

```
"dgrid/OnDemandGrid",
"dgrid/Selection",
"dgrid/extensions/Pagination"
```

> dgrid creation:

```
        var CustomGrid = declare([Grid, Selection, Pagination]);
        this.grid = new CustomGrid({
            columns: columns,
            collection: new Memory({ data: [] }),
            selectionMode: "toggle",
            keepScrollPosition: true,
            noDataMessage: this.sharedNls.errorMessages.invalidSearch,
            pagingLinks: true,
            pagingTextBox: true,
            firstLastArrows: true,
            minRowsPerPage: 5,
            rowsPerPage: 100
        }, this.gridContainer);
        this.grid.startup();
```

> Attaching events:

```
     on(this.grid, "(dgridPageChangeEventName)", lang.hitch(this, function (page) {
       // send notification code will be added here
       alert( "You are looking at page no " +  page);
      }));
```

> Issue:

As per above code **I need the page change event name** or work around so that i can write my custom code there to send notification to the user.

thanks!

Comment: Dear Downvoter... I didn't get what exactly you look in the question... if you are downvoting please comment.. or its just a random...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't a specific emitted event for this, because generally this can already be detected by aspecting after the `gotoPage` method used to switch pages:

```
aspect.after(this.grid, 'gotoPage', function (promise, args) {
    // promise is the promise returned from the original gotoPage
    // args are the original arguments passed, so args[0] is the requested page #
    promise.then(function () {
        console.log('Now viewing page ' + args[0]);
    });
    return promise;
});
```

PS: You should not be using both OnDemandGrid and Pagination in the same grid, [as mentioned in the documentation](https://github.com/SitePen/dgrid/blob/v0.4.0/doc/components/extensions/Pagination.md#pagination).  Mix Pagination into Grid directly.

Comment: thank you very much Ken... its working for me :)... done a little modification in your ans just added grid object at the start :).

Comment: Whoops, yeah.  Thanks.

Comment: Works like a charm! Although it would be great if the pagination extension can add such event. For other beginners like me, `aspect` is from `dojo/aspect`.